# Can you pass a matcher to a shared example in rspec?

Tags: rspec

I have the following situation. I have a shared example that gets passed in some hash as data and another hash with the expected data. Simplified it looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe "shared examples" do
  shared_examples "matching hash" do |data, expected_data|
    it 'matches' do
      expect(data).to include (expected_data)
    end
  end

  it_behaves_like "matching hash", { foo: '/foo/1', bar: '/bar' }, { foo: '/foo/1' }
end
```

I now have the issue, that for some values in the hash containing URLs, I don't want to check the complete string, but only the start. So my idea was to use a matcher like I would normally do and pass it in, inside the `expected_data`.

```
RSpec.describe "shared examples with passed in matcher" do
  shared_examples "matching hash" do |data, expected_data|
    it 'matches' do
      expect(data).to include (expected_data)
    end
  end

  it_behaves_like "matching hash", { foo: '/foo/1' }, { foo: start_with('/foo/') }
end
```

Sadly this fails with

```
Failure/Error: it_behaves_like "matching hash", { foo: '/foo/1' }, { foo: start_with('/foo/') }
  `start_with` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).
```

In this specific case I could solve it with passing a regex instead of `start_with` or adapt the shared example to explicitly grab the fuzzy data and compare it via the matcher.

But to me it would feel nicer, if there's was a way to pass matchers into shared examples. Is there any way to do this or is this just not possible?